# Imitate sprintf behaviour with str_replace?

Tags: php

Basically I have a situation like this:

```
$search = array(
   '?',
   '?'
);

$replace = array(
   '1',
   '2'
);
```

When I try:

```
str_replace($search,$replace,"First value: ? Second Value: ?");
```

I get:

```
"First value: 1 Second Value: 1"  //> Notice the "1" repetead
```

Instead of

```
 "First value: 1 Second Value: 2"
```

How could I get the second result (even without the use of str_replace)?

Comment: Not possible with str_replace. You'd need to repeatedly loop over the original string, finding each ? and replacing it individually.

Comment: @MarcB: do you mean I need to do a foreach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[preg_replace](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) has a limit parameter so you can use that instead:

```
$search = array(
   '/\?/',
   '/\?/'
);

$replace = array(
   '1',
   '2'
);

echo preg_replace($search, $replace, "First value: ? Second Value: ?", 1);

// output: First value: 1 Second Value: 2
```

You can use [array_fill](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) to build the search array:

```
preg_replace(array_fill(0, count($replace), '/\?/'), $replace, $subject, 1);
```

Comment: That will only work if you have two question marks.  If you have more than two `?` to replace, it will not work.

Comment: @roychri: "will not work" how? Give an example. Code works correctly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use str_replace for this.  It is the wrong function to use.

OR, change your ? by something else that is different for each.  Example:

```
$search = array(
   '\1',
   '\2'
);
$replace = array(
   'firstValue',
   'secondValue'
);
str_replace($search,$replace,"First value: \\1 Second Value: \\2");
```

Comment: Then you should use `sprintf()` then.  Why don't you use it? 
Simply do 
`$new = call_user_func_array('sprintf', array(str_replace("?", "%s", "First Value: ? Second Value: ?"), $replace))`

Answer (score 0):

If the amount of replacements is known or limited you can simply use string formatting functions. I like using vsprintf since it's easy to append replacement values to the stack.

In this case, to achieve the desired results using vsprintf:

```
$subject = 'First value: %s Second Value: %s';
$values = array('1', '2');
echo vsprintf($subject, $values);
```